# где правильнее определить функцию

Tags: qt

Где правильнее определить функцию которую я планирую использовать во всех созданных окнах(QWidget,QDialog,QMainWindow).

```
void MainWindow::moveToCenter()
{
    QDesktopWidget desktop;
    QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen()); 
    QPoint center = rect.center(); //координаты центра экрана
    center.setX(center.x() - (this->width()/2)); 
    center.setY(center.y() - (this->height()/2)); 
    move(center);
}
```

отдельным классом и подключать ? Или у кокого то родителя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если планируете ее использовать не только для текущего окна, но и для всех остальных, то сделайте общую функцию, например:

```cpp
void moveToCenter(QWidget& widget)
{
    QDesktopWidget desktop;
    QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen());
    QPoint center = rect.center(); //координаты центра экрана
    center.setX(center.x() - (widget.width()/2));
    center.setY(center.y() - (widget.height()/2));
    widget.move(center);
}

void moveToCenter(QWidget* widget)
{
    moveToCenter(*widget);
}
```

Ну и использование:

```cpp
QWidget *ww = new QWidget();
ww->show();

moveToCenter(ww);

QWidget w;
w.show();

moveToCenter(w);
```

Эту функцию можно будет вынести из `MainWindow`, или оставить в нем, но сделать статичной

Comment: все таки я не понял( Создать эти функции в mainwindow. То что у них названия одинаковые так надо? С использованием все понял)

Comment: Можете в mainwindow их создавать, можете вне mainwindow. Названия одинаковые но параметры разные, это называется "перегрузка". Позволяет использовать функции с одинаковыми именами для работы с разными данными